# @import doesn't work when suffix isn't .css?

Tags: html, css, import

This works:

```
@import   "foo.css"
```

This fails:

```
@import   "foo.cssabc"
```

Any reason for this?

Comment: I'm meeting with exactly this problem.

Comment: I would recommend marking some of your other questions as answered. This will entice people to help your more.

Comment: I'll tick it once someone answers correctly.

Answer (score 6):

The filename is irrelevant.

You just need to make sure your server is returning `Content-Type: text/css` for both.

Comment: I just checked via firebug there's no `Content-Type` header for both `.css` and `.cssabc` .But one works,the other fails.

Comment: @wamp how are you asserting this?

Comment: Haven't you ever used **firebug** ?

Comment: Interesting. I just looked at StackOverflow's CSS in Firebug's network tab, and `Content-Type` is not there. However, downloading with `curl -v` shows it. I suggest you use http://redbot.org/ to check what your server is returning, since Firebug seems not to show this particular header.